# If $\,f''(x) \ge f(x)$, for all $x\in[0,\infty),$ and $\,f(0)=f'(0)=1$, then is $\,f(x)>0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function, such that 
$\,f''(x) \ge f(x)$, for all $x\in\ [0,\infty)$, and
$ f(0)=f'(0)=1$. Can we deduce that $f$ is increasing?

I feel like it is, but I cannot see it. I can only show that to get it increasing it is enough to show that $f$ is non negative .

Comment: Think about it this way. You have that $f''(x)\geq f$ for all $x\in[0,\infty]$. Since $f(0)=f'(0)=1$ we know that $f''(0)\geq1$ and $f''(x)$ is just the rate of change of $f'(x)$ so $f'(x)$ is increasing and since it starts off positive $f$ must be increasing as well. Now you just need to formalize that.

Comment: Suppose there were some $x$ with $f(x) \leqslant 0$. By continuity, there is then a smallest $x_0 \in (0,+\infty)$ with $f(x_0) = 0$. What can you say about $f, f', f''$ on the interval $[0,x_0)$?

Comment: This is a very good problem ;Do you mind sharing source of these problems ?I am in great need of these.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following treatment is a standard way of dealing with *ordinary differential inequalities* using the ideas behind the proof of [Grönwald's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality):
\begin{align*}
f''\ge f &\quad\Longrightarrow\quad f''+f'\ge f'+f \\ 
&\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \mathrm{e}^{-x}\big((\,f''+f')-(\,f'+f\,)\big)\ge 0 \\ &\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\big(\mathrm{e}^{-x}(\,f'+f\,)\big)'\ge 0
\end{align*}
and thus, for all $x\ge 0$
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-x}\big(f'(x)+f(x)\big)\ge f'(0)+f(0)=2.
$$
Hence $\,f'(x)+f(x)\ge 2 \mathrm{e}^{x}$ and consequently
$$
\big(\mathrm{e}^{x}f(x)\big)'=\mathrm{e}^{x}\big(\,f'(x)+f(x)\big)
\ge 2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \mathrm{e}^{x}f(x)-f(0)
\ge \int_0^x 2\mathrm{e}^{2t}\,dt=\mathrm{e}^{2x}-1
$$
and finally
$\,f(x)\ge \mathrm{e}^{x},\,$ for all $x\ge 0$.

Since $\,f''(x)\ge f(x)\ge\mathrm{e}^x$, then $\,f'(x)-f'(0)= \int_0^x f''(t)\,dt=\int_0^x\mathrm{e}^t\,dt=\mathrm{e}^x-1$, and thus $\,f'(x)\ge\mathrm{e}^x$, which implies that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Very very nice!