# Extending the convexity of a twice differentiable function on a neighbourhood $[0,\delta)$ to the global domain $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function with $f(0)>0,~f'(0)>0$ and $$f''(x) =a(x) f(x),~\text{for all}~x \in [0,\infty),$$where, $a$ is a positive monotonically increasing continuous function on $[0,\infty)$. How can we show that $f=f(x)$ is strictly increasing and unbounded?

I can see that $f$ is strictly increasing and convex in a neighbourhood $[0, \delta)$ of $0$. But.....

1. How can we arrive at a contradiction for the assumption $1 \leq y(x) \leq M>1$ for $x \in [0,\infty)$?
2. How to use behavior of $y'$ and $y''$ for this dynamic divergence?
3. How to justify the existence of $K_N \in \mathbb R$ corresponding to any sufficiently large $N \in \mathbb N$ satisfying $y(x)>N$ whenever $x \geq K_N$.
4. Can we prove $y(x_1)<y(x_2)$ for any $x_1<x_2 \in [0,\infty)$?
5. How to extend the local behavior of $y$ on $[0,\delta)$ globally to $[0,\infty)$?

I could not establish one of the above analysis.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684292/42969

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.. I have edited some thing.

Comment: How can we say $a(x) f(x) \geq a(0) f(x)$ simply from $a(x) \geq a(0)>0$ without considering the sign of $f(x)$?

Comment: Oops, you are right. I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: Consider the largest interval $[0, \delta)$ on which $f$ is positive. The above method shows that $f$ increases on that interval, so that $f(\delta) = 0$ is not possible.

Comment: So we cannot choose such a $\delta$ at all, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $f$ has no zeros: If $f(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0 > 0$ then $f$ attains its (positive) maximum on $[0, x_0]$ at some point $c \in (0, x_0)$. At that point is $f'(c) = 0$ and
$$
   0 < a(c)f(c) = f''(c) \le  0 \, ,
$$
which is a contradiction.

So  $f$ is positive on $[0, \infty)$. Then $f''$ is positive on $[0, \infty)$ as well, so that $f'$ is strictly increasing. It follows that $f$ is (strictly) convex, strictly increasing and unbounded:
$$
 f(x) \ge f(0) + xf'(0) \, .
$$

*Note:* We have not used the monotony of the function $a$, only that it is strictly positive.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.....

Comment: @RIYASUDHEENTK: You are welcome. There was a small error which I have fixed now: The second derivative is less than *or equal to* zero at a maximum. Fortunately, that does not affect the proof.