# Prove or Disprove $f=0$ if $f$ is a twice differentiable function on the interval $[a,0],~a<0,$ satisfying $f(a)=f(0)=0$ and $f''(x)=-xf(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $f$ is a twice differentiable function on the interval $[a,0],~a<0,$ satisfying $f(a)=f(0)=0$ and $$f''(x)=-xf(x).$$Can we conclude that $f$ is identically zero on $[a,0]$? If so how? I am not getting any counter examples for this.

Comment: Are there any real functions such that $f’’(x) =-xf(x)\ ?$

Comment: Other than zero?

Comment: By the existence and uniqueness theorem, we can ensure there are lot of  such functions.

Comment: If $f'(a)=0$ then by the existence and uniqueness theorem you get the identically zero solution. If $f'(a)>0$ then $f(x)>0$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ and hence $f''(x)>0$, hence there is no way your solution will get back to zero because it will be growing monotonically. The same works for $f'(a)<0$. Hence, yes, $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: You can use the same approach as in one or your recent questions https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4404547/42969: If $f$ is not identically zero then $f$ attains a positive maximum or a negative minimum at a point $c \in (a, 0)$, and that leads to a contradiction.